# Разная навигация в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: android

Можно ли сделать так что бы на экранах mdpi и hdpi для навигации запускался NavigationDrawer, а для xhdpi и выше использовались для навигации табы? Если можно то опишете в кратце паттерн.

Comment: вы можете использовать разные xml с леяутами для разных dpi

Comment: А в Java проверять разрешение экрана и исходя из этого запускать обработчики или там тоже нужно писать отдельный класс для разрешения?

Comment: А зачем вам разрешение экрана, если вы хотитие исходить из dpi? Определите тип DPI, и исходите из этого?